# retrieving variable from PHP processing script?

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm using a PHP file upload processing script (uploadify.com) in order to allow users to upload images along with their form submission.  The processing script includes a step that gives that file a unique file name.  What I would like to do is retrieve that unique file name in order to include with my form submission to the database.

The uploading script is run externally and never reloads the form page.  Not sure if I can use session variables or POST/GET.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploadify sends ajax request to the php script that you specify to it via `script` settings.

Let's say you have file input field like this:

```
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
```

You can get that in your php script via `$_FILES` array like this:

```
var_dump($_FILES('file_upload'));
```

[See the uploadify's documentation for more information.](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

You can also check the source of php file that comes with uploadify package when you download it.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, my only problem is that the PHP processing script does a back end file rename to make it unique.  I can't take the value that is plugged into the form - somehow I have to get it from that back end back into my form post.  Sorry if I am misunderstanding this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running this PHP upload script AJAX style.  In that case I would suggest doing something like:

```
var filename = $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "url-to-php-script.php",
    data: "postVar=value"
    }).responseText;
```

In your php script you need to just echo out the filename and it will be placed in the variable filename.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Does this code go onto the form page?  And would I replace the URL with the PHP process script?  Do I change the variable name as well?  Sorry for the questions, I'm still a little confused.

Comment: Ok, I believe I have this setup as you said.  I am using:

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var targetFile = $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "uploadify/uploadify.php",
    data: "postVar=value"
    }).responseText;
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">document.write(targetFile);</script>

I have uploadify.php echo $targetFile (the renamed image) and nothing ever updates on the form page.  Can you see what I did wrong?

Comment: Yes this code would go onto your form page.  You would have to send the original filename as the data parameter. So, data: "filename: filename" or whatever they are called.  Then on the backend you would finish the upload and echo your new unique filename

Comment: According to uploadify's documentation, I can reference the file name being uploaded with "fileObj.name". I have tested this with an onComplete function and I am able to javascript alert myself with the original file name.  

So, would my code look like this:
<script type="text/javascript"> var targetFile = $.ajax({ async: false, type: "POST", url: "uploadify/uploadify.php", data: "fileObj.name" }).responseText; </script> 

I do a lot of design and I'm pretty new to this.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to get this working.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem, gald I could help.  Please mark the question as answered when you get a chance.